# Vertex editor in Qgis 3.0 : Snapping settings

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

**Context :**

I imported a grid point layer in Qgis 3.2 during my workflow, as seen in the picture below.

[image: Point layer]

I now need to edit another point layer. As I don't need the first layer, I had it hidden, but I need to keep it in the project for possible future use.

Using the vertex tool editor, I want to move a point to specific coordinates. However, when I want to select the point in the second layer, all the points from the first layer are selectable, even if the layer is not editable. As the points are rather tight, it becomes hard to select the right point from the layer.

[image: Second layer with wrongly selected point from the first layer]

According to the research I made, this behaviour is not to be expected, as discussed in [this link.](https://github.com/QGEP/QGEP/issues/330)

**Question :**

- Is it a bug, or is there a setting that I am missing? I need to snap the vertex editor only to the active layer, any other behaviour feels really confusing.
- Once the vertex is selected, is there another setting to enable or disable snapping to the hidden layers? In my mind, if a layer is hidden, it is meant to be forgotten until displayed again, so I would like to set Qgis according to that behaviour.

Comment: From the menubar, go to `Project > Snapping options`. Select the _Advanced Configuration_ option and only check the layer you're interested in. This should keep the snapping active for your checked layer only.

Comment: That would have been the most logical setup, however it is already set this was and I keep having that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, this is currently a bug in QGIS that has persisted since QGIS 3.0. I am a bit annoyed that this has not been fixed.

There is a Bug Report here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18628

This single issue is so significant that the majority of my team is not budging from QGIS 2.18.

There is no quick solution to this. One way we have been getting around this is by working in QGIS 2.18. The workspaces are backwards and forwards compatible.